# How to prevent increasing amounts of API calls from within Javascript?

Tags: javascript, api

The title may be a bit weir, but I don't really know how else to call it. My problem is as follows: I've built an API call which I'm repeatedly calling (every 5 seonds) with this javascript code in my html:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var openTicketRequests = [];
    function getOpenTickets() {
        // Abort all pending openTicketRequests
        for(var i=0; i<openTicketRequests.length; i++) {
            openTicketRequests[i].abort();
        }
        openTicketRequests.push(
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ticket/get_open",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    $(".open_tickets").empty(); // Empty the list of open tickets.
                    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                        $(".open_tickets").append(data[i].id + "<br/>");
                    }
                }
            }));
        setTimeout(getOpenTickets, 5000);
    }
});
```

This works fine. Sometimes I call it from a different place in the javascript so that it is run instantly. The problem with that is that it then updates every 2.5 seconds. If I call it again it then runs 3 times per 5 seconds, etc. etc. After a while of running that page, this call is being made about 20 times per 5 seconds instead of once per 5 seconds.

For this reason I added the openTicketRequests array which I loop over to abort the existing pending calls, but this obviously doesn't work very well.

So my question: what am I doing wrong? How can I abort all pending requests so that it is only run once every 5 seconds? All tips are welcome!

Comment: I think it's just a matter of clearing timeouts before starting another one

Comment: You want to handle it from differente pages like e.g. multiple tabs, right ?

Comment: [Window.clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout)

Comment: @Huangism - You're right, but how would I do that?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - I indeed want to handle it from multiple tabs. Would this make a difference?

Comment: It makes, because between two tabs you can't stop another's tab timeout. It needs another implementation for that. I can show you, if you want, btw, FishBasketGordo's answer is pretty nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the code to run every 5 seconds and an ad hoc call to the code should reset the 5 second interval, then you need to capture the return of `setTimeout` and clear it with `clearTimeout`*<sup>[[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearTimeout)</sup>* within `getOpenTickets`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var openTicketRequests = [];
    var timeoutID = null;
    function getOpenTickets() {
        // First clear the timer.
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);

        // Abort all pending openTicketRequests
        for(var i=0; i<openTicketRequests.length; i++) {
            openTicketRequests[i].abort();
        }
        openTicketRequests.push(
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ticket/get_open",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    $(".open_tickets").empty(); // Empty the list of open tickets.
                    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                        $(".open_tickets").append(data[i].id + "<br/>");
                    }
                }
            }));
        timeoutID = setTimeout(getOpenTickets, 5000);
    }
});
```

If you want the code to run every 5 seconds regardless of whether you've executed the code in an ad hoc fashion, I would separate the code that creates the regular call from the call itself and use `setInterval`*<sup>[[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)</sup>* instead of `setTimeout`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var openTicketRequests = [];
    function getOpenTickets() {
        // Abort all pending openTicketRequests
        for(var i=0; i<openTicketRequests.length; i++) {
            openTicketRequests[i].abort();
        }
        openTicketRequests.push(
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ticket/get_open",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    $(".open_tickets").empty(); // Empty the list of open tickets.
                    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                        $(".open_tickets").append(data[i].id + "<br/>");
                    }
                }
            }));
    }

    
    setInterval(getOpenTickets, 5000);
});
```

Now, you can call `getOpenTickets` ad hoc whenever you want, but it's not going to compound the regular call.

---

#### Reference

- [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)
- [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearTimeout)
- [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)
- [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval)

Comment: I don't think this addresses the issue. I think the OP means that the next timed call should be 5 seconds after the ad hoc calls.

Comment: @Liam In that case he'll want to keep track of the handle `setInterval` returns and clear it then call it again whenever an ad hoc call occurs, correct? ...Which is basically what FishBasketGordo just said in his new edit.

Comment: I see. Didn't parse it like that at first. I've updated my answer with a solution to both scenarios.